# Matching multiple strings and join

Tags: r, string, join, match

I am having difficulties with matching multiple strings in r. The dataframe that I have looks like this:

```
      Var1                                      Var2
1   SJDJWK   P04TGI7F3;P030Y7Y11;PE35RV747;Q2UKLVVX4
2  ODJSMDK   Q2UKLVVX4;PWER00711;PE35RV747;Q2UKLVVX4
3 JDKSAKDJ                       PE35RV747;P0F071G1G
```

I would like to match the strings that are separated with ";" with the values in the following dataframe:

```
      Var_x    Var_y
1 P04TGI7F3     good
2 P030Y7Y11   normal
3 PE35RV747      bad
4 Q2UKLVVX4   normal
```

So that the resulting dataframe looks like:

```
      Var1                                      Var2                    Var3
1   SJDJWK   P04TGI7F3;P030Y7Y11;PE35RV747;Q2UKLVVX4  good;normal;bad;normal
2  ODJSMDK   Q2UKLVVX4;PWER00711;PE35RV747;Q2UKLVVX4       normal;bad;normal
3 JDKSAKDJ                       PE35RV747;P0F071G1G                     bad
```

So far, I tried to do this with a fuzzy join:

```
fuzzy_left_join(Data1, Data2, by = c("Var2"="Var_x"), match_fun = str_detect)
```

This does the job, but it uses a lot of memory (my dataset is very large and R stops working). I was trying to do this with a for loop, but I cannot figure out how to do it. Someone who knows?

Comment: One options it so reshape wide to long format, then use normal join, then again reshape long to wide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea via `tidyverse`. We separate the rows, merge on the second data frame and again concatenate based on `Var1`,

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>% 
 separate_rows(Var2) %>% 
 left_join(df2, by = c('Var2' = 'Var_x')) %>% 
 group_by(Var1) %>% 
 summarise_all(funs(paste(., collapse = ';')))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 3
>   Var1     Var2                                    Var_y                 
>   <fct>    <chr>                                   <chr>                 
> 1 JDKSAKDJ PE35RV747;P0F071G1G                     bad;NA                
> 2 ODJSMDK  Q2UKLVVX4;PWER00711;PE35RV747;Q2UKLVVX4 normal;NA;bad;normal  
> 3 SJDJWK   P04TGI7F3;P030Y7Y11;PE35RV747;Q2UKLVVX4 good;normal;bad;normal
> ```

If you do not want to include `NAs`, we can omit before joining (as @akrun mentions), i.e.

```
df1 %>% 
 separate_rows(Var2) %>% 
 filter(Var2 %in% df2$Var_x) %>% 
 left_join(df2, by = c('Var2' = 'Var_x')) %>% 
 group_by(Var1) %>% 
 summarise_all(funs(paste(., collapse = ';')))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 3
>   Var1     Var2                                    Var_y                 
>   <fct>    <chr>                                   <chr>                 
> 1 JDKSAKDJ PE35RV747                               bad                   
> 2 ODJSMDK  Q2UKLVVX4;PE35RV747;Q2UKLVVX4           normal;bad;normal     
> 3 SJDJWK   P04TGI7F3;P030Y7Y11;PE35RV747;Q2UKLVVX4 good;normal;bad;normal
> ```

Comment: Perhaps you need a `filter` before `left_join` to avoid the NA i.e. `%>% filter(Var2 %in% df2$Var_x)`

Comment: @akrun I thought about it but I left them there to also represent strings that do not match. Let me add it though for completion

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sotos

Answer (score 2):

Using base R, loop through Var2, split on `";"`, then *match*:

```
df1$Var3 <- sapply(df1$Var2, function(i){
  paste(df2$Var_y[ match(unlist(strsplit(i, split = ";")), df2$Var_x) ], collapse = ";")
})

#       Var1                                    Var2                   Var3
# 1   SJDJWK P04TGI7F3;P030Y7Y11;PE35RV747;Q2UKLVVX4 good;normal;bad;normal
# 2  ODJSMDK Q2UKLVVX4;PWER00711;PE35RV747;Q2UKLVVX4   normal;NA;bad;normal
# 3 JDKSAKDJ                     PE35RV747;P0F071G1G                 bad;NA
```

**Note:** I am aware my output has NAs in Var3, and OP's expected output doesn't. But I preferred to keep NAs, so that we can match each "bad/normal" to corresponding string by position in original string. Of course, if OP wishes, they can be removed using `na.omit`:

```
df1$Var3 <- sapply(df1$Var2, function(i){
  paste(na.omit(df2$Var_y[ match(unlist(strsplit(i, split = ";")), df2$Var_x) ]), collapse = ";")
})
#       Var1                                    Var2                   Var3
# 1   SJDJWK P04TGI7F3;P030Y7Y11;PE35RV747;Q2UKLVVX4 good;normal;bad;normal
# 2  ODJSMDK Q2UKLVVX4;PWER00711;PE35RV747;Q2UKLVVX4      normal;bad;normal
# 3 JDKSAKDJ                     PE35RV747;P0F071G1G                    bad
```

Comment: What happened to `Var3` there is no `NA` in expected output :)

Comment: @snoram haha, knew someone would mention this. I'd keep the NAs so we can match each bad/normal to original string position.

Answer (score 2):

Playing with  `data.table`

```
df2[df1[, unlist(tstrsplit(Var2, ";")), Var1], 
    on = .(Var_x = V1)
    ][,
      lapply(.SD, function(x) paste(x[!is.na(x)], collapse = ";")), 
      by = Var1
      ]

       Var1                                   Var_x                  Var_y
1:   SJDJWK P04TGI7F3;P030Y7Y11;PE35RV747;Q2UKLVVX4 good;normal;bad;normal
2:  ODJSMDK Q2UKLVVX4;PWER00711;PE35RV747;Q2UKLVVX4      normal;bad;normal
3: JDKSAKDJ                     PE35RV747;P0F071G1G                    bad
```

Comment: What happened to 2nd column?

Comment: @zx8754 sorry...?

Comment: Compare your 2nd column to OPs expected output.

Answer (score 2):

Another option with `gsubfn` where we create a `list` of key/val pairs in the `replacement` of `gsubfn` for the `pattern` of characters that is not a `;`.  Note that there are some cases where the words are not present in the 
'df2'.  If all the replacements are there, then the second `gsub` is not needed (assuming that in the example it is not provided)

```
library(gsubfn)
df1$Var_y <-  gsub(";[A-Z0-9]+", "", gsubfn("[^;]+",  
                setNames(as.list(df2$Var_y), df2$Var_x), df1$Var2))
df1
#      Var1                                    Var2                  Var_y
#1   SJDJWK P04TGI7F3;P030Y7Y11;PE35RV747;Q2UKLVVX4 good;normal;bad;normal
#2  ODJSMDK Q2UKLVVX4;PWER00711;PE35RV747;Q2UKLVVX4      normal;bad;normal
#3 JDKSAKDJ                     PE35RV747;P0F071G1G                    bad
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Var1 = c("SJDJWK", "ODJSMDK", "JDKSAKDJ"), 
  Var2 = c("P04TGI7F3;P030Y7Y11;PE35RV747;Q2UKLVVX4", 
"Q2UKLVVX4;PWER00711;PE35RV747;Q2UKLVVX4", "PE35RV747;P0F071G1G"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))

df2 <- structure(list(Var_x = c("P04TGI7F3", "P030Y7Y11", "PE35RV747", 
"Q2UKLVVX4"), Var_y = c("good", "normal", "bad", "normal")), 
     class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))
```

Answer (score 0):

In base `R` you can build a named vector from the second `data.frame`, then after splitting we lookup all relevant values in this named vector, drop the NAs and paste back together.

```
df1$Var3 <- sapply(
  strsplit(df1$Var2,";"), 
  function(x) paste(na.omit(setNames(df2$Var_y,df2$Var_x)[x]), collapse=";"))

df1
#       Var1                                    Var2                   Var3
# 1   SJDJWK P04TGI7F3;P030Y7Y11;PE35RV747;Q2UKLVVX4 good;normal;bad;normal
# 2  ODJSMDK Q2UKLVVX4;PWER00711;PE35RV747;Q2UKLVVX4      normal;bad;normal
# 3 JDKSAKDJ                     PE35RV747;P0F071G1G                    bad
```